# Gaussian Reduction Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $u$ and $v$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The main reduction, of this algorithm, step is: find a number $x$ such that the norm $||u-xv||^2$ is minimized, it is easy to see that the optimal value of $x$ which minimizes $||u-xv||^2$ is $\dfrac{u\cdot v}{||v^2||}$. How I will be able to proof this?. How I will be able to understand this in geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure what this has to do with Gaussian Elimination (or is Gaussian Reduction something different?), but there is a very geometric meaning to that number.

Notice that $x\mathbf{v}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is the parametrization of a *line* through the origin in the direction of $\mathbf{v}$. Call this line $\ell$. Therefore your question is equivalent to asking: What is closest point on the line $\ell(x) = x\mathbf{v}$ to the vector $\mathbf{u}$ (which we can regard as a point here)?

The answer to this question is obviously the perpendicular distance from $\mathbf{u}$ to the line. We can interpret the above in the following way. Consider the line segment joining a point $x\mathbf{v}$ on the line to the point $\mathbf{u}$. This is the directed line segment given by $\mathbf{u}-x\mathbf{v}$. When $x=0$, this directed line segment is just the vector $\mathbf{u}$ itself. As we increase or decrease $x$, we expect to eventually reach a point in which the line segment will become perpendicular to the line $\ell$, and it is this point which will minimize the distance between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\ell$.

Therefore we wish to find the $x$ such that $\mathbf{u}-x\mathbf{v}$ is perpendicular to the line (or more precisely, perpendicular to the direction vector of the line, that is $\mathbf{v}$). Vectors are perpendicular if and only if their dot product is zero, so we get
$$0=(\mathbf{u}-x\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v} - x\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}$$
Since $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v} = \|\mathbf{v}\|^2$, we then get
$$x = \frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|^2}$$
Incidentally, the multiple of $\mathbf{v}$ associated with this number is called the **projection of $\mathbf{u}$ onto $\mathbf{v}$**, given by
$$\mathrm{proj}_{\mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{u})=\left(\frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|^2}\right)\mathbf{v}=\left(\frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}\right)\hat{\mathbf{v}}$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{v}}$ the is unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{v}$.

With respect to the previous discussion, $x = \frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|^2}$ can be interpreted as follows: One term of $\|\mathbf{v}\|$ in the denominator is used to *normalize* the vector $\mathbf{v}$. The remaining term $\frac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}$ is the distance we need to travel from the origin in the direction of $\mathbf{v}$ to reach the point where our line segment becomes orthogonal to $\ell$.